# kube-ops-view with Kubernetes KinD

Tags: kubernetes

Tried to configure **kube-ops-view** on a local cluster created using Kubernetes KinD not able to access it.

1. helm install kube-ops-view stable/kube-ops-view

```
WARNING: This chart is deprecated
NAME: kube-ops-view
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Dec  2 15:05:45 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
To access the Kubernetes Operational View UI:

1. First start the kubectl proxy:

   kubectl proxy

2. Now open the following URL in your browser:

   http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/kube-ops-view/

Please try reloading the page if you see "ServiceUnavailable / no endpoints available for service", pod creation might take a moment.
```

2. **kubectl proxy**

```
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

3. **kubectl get pods**

```
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-ops-view-7bc8944b46-nmc8k   1/1     Running   0          5m9s
```

4. **kubectl get service**

```
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kube-ops-view   ClusterIP   10.96.242.129   <none>        80/TCP    5m28s
```

5. **kubectl get deployment**

```
NAME            READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-ops-view   1/1     1            1           5m48
```

6. **kubectl describe deployment kube-ops-view**

```
Name:                   kube-ops-view
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Wed, 02 Dec 2020 15:05:45 +0800
Labels:                 app.kubernetes.io/instance=kube-ops-view
                        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                        app.kubernetes.io/name=kube-ops-view
                        app.kubernetes.io/part-of=kube-ops-view
                        app.kubernetes.io/version=20.4.0
                        helm.sh/chart=kube-ops-view-1.2.4
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
                        meta.helm.sh/release-name: kube-ops-view
                        meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Selector:               app.kubernetes.io/name=kube-ops-view,app.kubernetes.io/part-of=kube-ops-view
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=kube-ops-view
                    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                    app.kubernetes.io/name=kube-ops-view
                    app.kubernetes.io/part-of=kube-ops-view
                    app.kubernetes.io/version=20.4.0
                    helm.sh/chart=kube-ops-view-1.2.4
  Service Account:  default
  Containers:
   kube-ops-view:
    Image:      hjacobs/kube-ops-view:20.4.0
    Port:       8080/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Limits:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  128Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        80m
      memory:     64Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    http-get http://:8080/health delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   kube-ops-view-7bc8944b46 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age    From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----   ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  5m58s  deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set kube-ops-view-7bc8944b46 to 1
```

Trying to access using the URL but it's not working

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/kube-ops-view/

Answer (score 1):

Got it fixed

Deleted the kube-ops-view deployment and svc.

`helm install --set rbac.create=true --set ingress.enabled=true kube-ops-view stable/kube-ops-view`